# Why was this edit updating outdated information rejected?

Tags: support, edits, answers, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I know this question [has been asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) on Meta a number of times before, but I do not understand why reviewers [rejected my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28731232) with the response "this edit was intended to address the author of the post" when that was not the case. I tried to follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) as closely as possible, and correcting outdated information is definitely what edits are allowed to do.

Did I overlook something and were the reviewers right in rejecting?

Comment: The fact that GetPartsOfType is deprecated and that the indentation is broken. That is a part of the question. by fixing that, you are changing the meaning of the question, no?

Comment: How is code indentation and GetPartsOfType part of the question? I edited an answer, and the question did not mention GetPartsOfType.

Comment: If you left the existing contents and edited in the new version it would have been accepted most likely.

Comment: @Warcupine yes that makes sense, was fixing the indentation still right then?

Comment: Probably okay to fix indention assuming it doesn't change anything in the execution, I don't know if that is the case in C# though.

Comment: It doesn't. I'll propose a new edit with correcting the author's whitespace, and add the new implementation below it

Comment: Write your own answer with the new syntax instead.

Comment: @Tom I feel like that would be somewhat unfair, since the author's question is what helped me in the first place. The method is exactly the same, only the way in which ImageParts are retrieved isn't

Comment: In that case it might be better to just leave the comment I'd already posted, right?

Comment: @asdf101 - it is likely that your edit will be rejected again (I am sure I would've rejected it if I came across it). Editors who do not yet have a full edit privilege should not change the answers of others (I mean, semantically). The best thing you can do is to ping the author and ask *them* to make the edit. If they are unresponsive in a reasonable timeframe, consider posting an answer as suggested by yivi with proper credit. Make it a community wiki if you still feel bad about it (but you should not - SO is a collaborative place, not a competition)

Comment: @OlegValter is that an unwritten rule? Because I did not find that anywhere in the guidelines. The author hasn't posted since september.

Comment: @asdf101 - this is a judgement call (code edits) and a common courtesy (asking the author -> posting an answer with proper credit). There is no explicit "do not do ever" - this depends on the change. In your case you made the answer something it was not and this lead to rejection as "intended to address the author of the post" (btw, this is an canned response from an option we select when reviewing suggested edits - so this is one of the official reasons to reject an edit as well.

Comment: I'd say the comment you left is just fine - despite the OP not being active posted, last time they logged in was 7 hours ago, so pinging them (and preferably addressing them so as they know you want the info to be included in the post) most likely won't go to waste.

Comment: I personally would not have approved of an edit that simply fixed the indention of the code since whitespace doesn't matter to the C# compiler.  I mean you also changed a `var` to a `string` without any reason.  You also can't change `imageParts` without also changing `sourceSlidePart` more than likely.  **The most important fact is that the syntax used in the answer is still valid.** I would have rejected your edit for thos reasons

Comment: @SecurityHound [`GetIdOfPart` returns a string.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpartcontainer.getidofpart?view=openxml-2.8.1). The only thing that I can't find that doesn't make sense is where is the depreciation notice.

Comment: @Braiam - That isn't the line I was concerned about. `.. sourceSlidePart.ImageParts;` is what i was concerned about.

Comment: @SecurityHound " I mean you also changed a var to a string without any reason" you said there wasn't a reason to change it, there is. C# is strongly typed, using implicit typing is usually not recommended.

Comment: @SecurityHound what do you mean exactly? `sourceSlidePart` is exactly the same object as before. But yes, the syntax is still valid. Whitespace is just a formatting thing but it removes the horizontal scrollbar from the code and makes it easier to copy/paste. There is literally no reason to use `var` instead of `string` though, if it was a `Dictionary<something, something>` I'd understand.

Comment: @Braiam `var` in C# just means "figure out the type for me at compile time", not "this variable is of a variant type"; the compiler won't let you change the type of variable once declared. So, there is no reason to change `var` to `string`. Some of us use `var` all the time so that finding variable names is easier; my eyes don't have to zig-zag left and right for different types; all of the variable names are four characters in from the indent level.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I know what var means, and I'm sure that C# guys are alergic to that. It basically removes one of the "strengths" of strong typing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your edit, while well intentioned, removed information form the platform.

It's very well that a new syntax exists, but some other users may still benefit from the old syntax. We all have had to work with not fully updated technology now and then.

Instead of editing the existing answer, post your own, suggesting the new syntax. Credit the old answer if the new one you would post benefits clearly from the other one. Giving credit where it's due is expected in the platform.

As a general rule, editing code in answers is fine if you are correcting an obvious mistake. To provide updated information, I believe posting a new answer (specifying the circumstances under which the new information applies, linking the appropriate documentation if possible, etc) is a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think leaving the comment I already had posted is best, since it already contains all information future OpenXml users should need. The documentation is itself out of date unfortunately, the only way I knew GetPartOfType was outdated was because Visual Studio warned me.

Comment: "removed information form the platform" [citation needed] Nothing is ever removed from the site. The revision history is literally public on non-deleted post.

Comment: Wow. I didn’t know. That sounds like great feature. Next time I read an answer I’ll make sure to read the whole edit history. Maybe a previous version is completely different and more useful. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Braiam It makes that information inaccessible to anyone who doesn't check the revision history - even if you know that's an option, which I suspect most visitors to the site probably don't, you have no way of knowing that there's a different version of the code in it. Or do you expect users to check the full revision history of every single answer they read?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery and who cares about that? You, me or the one that actually is looking for an up to date solution to their problem? Who is more important of those? Hint: the last ;)

Comment: @Braiam And I guess the people who need the older solution don't matter at all?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery and yet, they are 0.000000001%. Should the rest just be kept back just because some don't want to move forward?

Comment: @Braiam No, they could read the new answer that yivi suggests the OP create... :/

Comment: @Braiam That's a strawman, nobody is suggesting keeping the rest back. The suggestion is to have *both* solutions available.

Comment: @HereticMonkey except that OP will not create it. For OP, the best solution is to make the answer better, not just duplicate it.